# MailChimp PHP Script to Pull Lists

Tags: php, json, mailchimp

I'm attempting to write a .JSON to pull a list of subscribers from my MailChimp account. I've followed the documentation on the website and have the following:

```
{
    "name": "export/export",
    "description": "MailChimp Export",
    "require": {
        "mailchimp/mailchimp": "dev-

master",
        "apigen/apigen": "~4.1@dev"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Ben Loya",


"email": "bal2155@columbia.edu"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}


$apikey = '6e1f2f874b81bbbd8a8d1dcae88353c1-us7';
$list_id = 'CUFSN Members';
$chunk_size = 4096; //in bytes
$url = 'http://us7.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list?apikey='.$apikey.'&id='.$list_id;

/** a more robust client can be built using fsockopen **/
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
if (!$handle) {
  echo "failed to access url\n";
} else {
  $i = 0;
  $header = array();
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, $chunk_size);
    if (trim($buffer)!=''){
      $obj = json_decode($buffer);
      if ($i==0){
        //store the header row
        $header = $obj;
      } else {
        //echo, write to a file, queue a job, etc.
        echo $header[0].': '.$obj[0]."\n";
      }
      $i++;
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

When I run `composer install` I get the following:

```
[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 15:
$apikey = '6e1f2f874
  ------------------^
  Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

What's wrong with my syntax? I'm very new to the .JSON format - forgive any stupid and/or obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you using http://jsonlint.com/ to check the syntax.

There is space after "mailchimp/mailchimp": "dev-", that should not be there.

---

To avoid these json typos, you can use install package via CLI like this: `composer require mailchimp/mailchimp`.